# Get XML data from a requests.post in Django

Tags: django, xml

I'm sending a request like this in Django:

```
response = requests.post('https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions', headers=headers,
                         params=params, data=data_ps)
```

When I `print(response.text)` I got the following answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<transaction>
  <date>2020-08-22T14:57:23.000-03:00</date>
  <code>CCBA67EC-D4C8-42F2-BC84-15C910A36B84</code>
</transaction>
```

How can I get the code number (CCBA67EC-D4C8-42F2-BC84-15C910A36B84)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python untangle module for the same. https://untangle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Here is the link to the module